# Why would anyone want to bind service (without creating it), instead of using a Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

Until today, I used services by **starting** them, using `startService()`, because I needed to do work also when all the activities was destroyed.

Now, I have a task that needs to be done in the background as long as my activity is alive.

Is there a reason for me to bind the activity to a service instead of doing the work in a separate thread?

It leads me to the question in the title:
Why would anyone want to bind service (without creating it before), instead of using a `Thread`?

Comment: what do you mean by *without creating it before* ?

Comment: @Blackbelt It's not the main point of the question, but anyway - It only to emphasize that I don't need the service to run when the activity isn't alive (If I start using startService, it will keep running also after the activity will be destroyed

Comment: but you already answered your own question. The execution of a task is coupled with the execution of the activity.

Comment: @Blackbelt Indeed, and that's why I'm asking, what is the benefit of binding to service? Why not using a thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a reason for me to bind the activity to a service 
>   instead of doing the work in a separate thread?

If your thread lives in a non static member variable of the activity and the activity is recreated after screen rotation your thread is lost or has to be recreated.
With a service you can reconnect to the service after rotation.

Instead of using a naked thread or a service i prefer to use a LoaderManager with an AsyncTask to do the background task while the activity is visible. The LoaderManager is also capable of reconnecting to the running AsyncTask

I avoid using static member variable for thread/AsyncTask because of memory leaking issues.

Answer (score 1):

`Services` and `Thread` have two different goals. As you mentioned, `Service` can live longer after the activity was destroyed. Depending on the Service you subclassed it runs or not  on the `UI Thread`. They have their own life cycle and are a construct of the Android SDK. `Thread`s are unit of executions whose flow is parallel to the ui thread. It allows you to execute long term tasks leaving the ui responsive. The Thread lives as long as its run's method. You should make sure that its execution is completed before your `Activity` or `Fragment` calls its `onDestroy` method.

> Why would anyone want to bind service  instead of using a Thread?

The answer is *it depends*. If you need to run your task also when you `Activity` is destroyed, then a Service is the natural choice. Otherwise you can use a simple thread. Think, for instance, about downloading a huge file from the net. You want to run this task also when the activity is not at screen but, at the same time, you want to show to the user the current progress (in percentage maybe) of the download. If you are using a Service to run this task, this one holds also those information. To update your UI, which is part of the Activity, you could either Broadcast those information, or retrive the `Service` object, the one you get when your service is bound, to retrieve this information (providing a delegate). Since you get an instance of your service, you can use it to send different kind of commands (e.g. stop the download).

Comment: Thanks for the deep explanation, but I don't understand how it answers my question. You gave an example where the task needs to be done regardless of whether the activity is alive or not, while I asked about the situation where I need the task to be done as long as the activity is alive

Comment: *while I asked about the situation where I need the task to be done as long as the activity is alive*. You can still use both. I personally use a Thread, if I have to run a long term task bound to the Activity/Fragment.